# Does basis for col A matter?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH0Cx.png)

A and B is row equivalent to B. Then Col A becomes {[3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]}, and it makes basis of col A equals to [3, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1].
Then is it possible to say basis of col A is [1, 2/3, 1/3], [1, 1/2, 1/2]?
Do we have to say bases of col A are column vectors of matrix A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking if you can write $Col(A)=Span(v_1,v_2)$, where $v_1,v_2$ are the two vectors you wrote down, as $Span(\frac{v_1}{3},\frac{v_2}{3})$.

Clearly, if a subspace $W$ is determined by the linear span of $n$ vectors, let's say $W=Span(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ we have that, as $\alpha v_1 \in Span(v_1)\  \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{K}$, $Span(v_1,\dots,v_n)=Span(\alpha v_1,\dots,\alpha v_n)$.

So in your case it's obvious that you can write the column space as a linear span of the vectors you prefer, substituting one or more with scaled ones or linearly combined ones.

Comment: so the form of basis does not matter: it does not have to be exact column vector of original matrix? Because my professor talked about it bit vaguely.

Comment: You are right, and the cause is written above: $Span(\alpha v)=Span(v) \ \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{K} \setminus \{0\}$